# Abstract class selectively expose methods based on derived type

Tags: c++, abstract-class, factory, conventions

I am writing an program that implements a factory `TimeManager` to generate two types of objects; a `Timer` and a `StopWatch`. Both of these objects are derived from an abstract class `TimePiece`, and share common methods. I would like the factory to return type `TimePiece`, but because `Timer` implements extra methods, I cant. How can I make `TimePiece` expose `Timer`'s extra methods without exposing them to `StopWatch` when those respective types are created? I hope this makes sense, as it is a little hard to explain.

TimeManager.h

```
enum TimePieceType{TIMER, STOP_WATCH};

class TimeManager {
public:
    TimeManager();
    ~TimeManager();

    void Tick();
    TimePiece* AddTimePiece(TimePieceType timeType);
};
```

TimePiece.h

```
enum RunningState { STOPPED, RUNNING, PAUSED };

class TimePiece {
private:
    unsigned long startTime = 0;
    unsigned long currentTime = 0;
    unsigned long pauseOffset = 0;

protected:
    Time time;
    RunningState state = STOPPED;

public:
    TimePiece() = default;
    virtual ~TimePiece() = default;

    void Stop();
    void Start();
    void Pause();
    void Resume();
    void Reset();
    virtual void Tick();

    Time GetTime();
    RunningState GetState();
    virtual uint8_t GetId() = 0;
};
```

StopWatch.h

```
class StopWatch : public TimePiece {
private:
    uint8_t watchId = 0;
    static int8_t currentId;
    
public:
    StopWatch();
    virtual ~StopWatch();

    uint8_t GetId();
};
```

Timer.h

```
class Timer : public TimePiece {
private:
    uint8_t timerId = 0;
    static int8_t currentId;
    unsigned long timeout;

public:
    Timer();
    ~Timer();

    void Tick() override;

    void SetTimeoutMs(unsigned long timeout);
    void SetTimeoutSec(unsigned long timeout);

    uint8_t GetId();
    Time GetRemainingTime();
    unsigned long GetTimeout();
};
```

Comment: What does "expose Timer's extra methods" mean? `TimePiece` has no control over what any derived class overrides, or what additional method it defines. C++ simply does not work this way.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! You are correct, this was a misunderstood aspect of the language on my part. I figured that was the case. I was just looking for another way to achieve this functionality. The selected answer solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return `TimePiece*` because the two subclasses are sharing `TimePiece` for its implementation, not for its interface.

A simple approach is to give `TimeManager` two separate methods:

```
Timer* AddTimer();
StopWatch* AddStopWatch();
```

You can exploit polymorphic behavior if you need the `Remove` method:

```
void RemoveTimePiece(TimePiece*);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Admittedly, I am a little ashamed I did not think of this obvious solution myself. Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean about "Exploit polymorphic behavior" with the remove method?

Comment: @shortCircuit77 I assumed that at some point you would need to add the corresponding `Remove...` method to the `TimeManager` to deal with the items you've added. This is a common pattern for situations when the manager object retains ownership of the objects it creates. I wanted to say that you don't need two separate `Remove` methods, because both classes derive from `TimePiece`, so you can take advantage of the common base class.